# pytest installation in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am new to programming. I was configuring PyCharm community edition for python development in the following link: https://realpython.com/pycharm-guide/

I want to try the pytest option after configuring in setting/tool and choose "default test runner : Pytest". When trying to run the test in the IDE I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pytest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'
```

Tried fix option from python integrated tools and had this error:

[Pycharm Error while trying to fix pytest package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRUW8.png)

I checked PIP packages from cmd: using the following commands as recommended in the official python guide:

1) `pip --version` to check the installed version and it returned the version number `pip 19.2.3` from `c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)`
2) `python -m pip install -U pip setuptools wheel`
the check succeeded except for wheel which fail with an error as you could see below:

```
    C:\Users\user_name>python -m pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A1748>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A1808>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A1910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A19E8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A1AC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/pip/
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (19.2.3)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036E5358>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/setuptools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03684EC8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/setuptools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A1E80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/setuptools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A1E50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/setuptools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A1D48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/setuptools/
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (41.2.0)
Collecting wheel
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A1F58>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/wheel/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A1B98>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/wheel/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A1A30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/wheel/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A1970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/wheel/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036A11A8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/wheel/


  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
```

I tried to repair repair/uninstall and install still these error appear
i tried  bootstrap it from the standard library:

`python -m ensurepip --default-pip`

```
C:\Users\user_name>python -m ensurepip --default-pip
Looking in links: c:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyly1wzwb
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (41.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (19.2.3)
```

### Update 1

Surprisingly I did not find the python path added to Windows environment variable when I checked that but I was sure that I checked that option when I installed python 3.8 package "Add python 3.8 to PATH" I added the path manually to windows through "edit the system environment variable" but still have this problem

Comment: What does `pip show pytest` show?

Comment: i did not try this. is it command in cmd terminal or shall be used in PyCharm IDE ?

Comment: It is a command to be run in terminal.

Comment: Nothing appear after executing this command in cmd

Comment: so that is the issue. In your case, pytest is not installed. Run `pip install pytest` and that should resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried pytest command as you recommended above and it ended with same error


ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytest